# How to use score tags on Google Play Game leaderboards?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games, leaderboard

I want to send a specific tag with my score when I think the score is valid to try to eliminate fraud scores (as suggested in point 3.5 on the [quality checklist](https://developers.google.com/games/services/checklist#3_leaderboards)) but I can't find how to use it anywhere. I know how to send the tag but where do I tell the `Google Play Game Services` which tag is a good tag?

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps

**Step1: Creating a leaderboard**
For a new game
To create a leaderboard for a new and unpublished game, go to the Google Play Console entry for your game, select the Leaderboard tab on the left, then click the Add new Leaderboard button.
[image]

Then, simply fill out the information required for this leaderboard.
[image]

Click Save, and your leaderboard will be made available in "Ready to publish" mode. Once you publish your game, all of your game's leaderboards will be published with it.

For a published game
To create an additional leaderboard for a game that has already been published, follow the same steps as above. The only difference is that the Save button will be relabeled as Save as the draft and your leaderboard will be in a "Ready to test" mode. For more information on testing an updated version of a game, see Publishing Your Game Changes.

Once you've tested your leaderboard and are happy with it, you can republish your game with the new leaderboards, and they will be pushed out to the world.

**Step2: Updating the player's score**
The following code snippet shows how your app can update the player’s score:

```
Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
        .submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard_id), 1337);
```

A good practice is to define the leaderboard ID in your strings.xml file, so your game can reference the leaderboards by resource ID. When making calls to update and load player scores, make sure to also follow these best practices for to avoid exceeding your API quota.

**Step3: Displaying a leaderboard**
To display leaderboard, call LeaderboardsClient.getLeaderboardIntent() to get an Intent to create the default leaderboard user interface. Your game can then bring up the UI by calling startActivityForResult.

The following code snippet shows how your app can update the player’s score. In the code snippet, RC_LEADERBOARD_UI is an arbitrary integer for the request code.

```
private static final int RC_LEADERBOARD_UI = 9004;

private void showLeaderboard() {
    Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
            .getLeaderboardIntent(getString(R.string.leaderboard_id))
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Intent>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Intent intent) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_LEADERBOARD_UI);
                }
            });
}
```

Notice that even though no result is returned, we have to use startActivityForResult so that the API can obtain the identity of the calling package.

Comment: Those are the steps for creating a leaderboard which I already have. I asked how to use score tags.

Comment: Submit a score to a leaderboard for the currently signed in player. The score is ignored if it is worse (as defined by the leaderboard configuration) than a previously submitted score for the same player.

follow this link you can get more help with tags handling 


https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboards#submitScore(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String,%20long,%20java.lang.String)